# VBA ADO Date Formatting on Mixed Data Input

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado, date-formatting

we are trying to use ADO to read data from a closed workbook, remove any whitespace and convert any incorrectly keyed dates into a valid format. Once the data has been cleansed, it's uploaded into a custom app.

We are using ADO for speed purposes as we have found using VBA to open/manipulate/close takes too long, meaning we miss our upload target time (we have multiple workbooks we need to apply this to).

The problem we have is converting the dates to a valid format. Dates are entered into the workbook either as dd/mm/yy or dd.mm.yy - we have no control over this, the template was created years ago and we are unable to update it and apply data validation.

**Ideas We Have Tried:** We have a few ideas, but have not been successful, does anyone know if any of these suggestions could work / suggest alternate ideas?

**Check for a "." and apply a Replace():** `If InStr(rs.Fields("Date").Value, ".") > 0 Then rs.Fields("Date").Value = Replace(rs.Fields("Date").Value, ".", "/")`

This works when the column is read into the record set as type 202: adVarWChar, unfortunatly as the majority of the dates are valid, the data in the record set is set as type 7: adDate, when looping, once we get to an invalid date format (with the dots), we get a debug error:

*"you cannot record changes because a value you entered violates the settings defined for this table or list (for example, a value is less than the minimum or greater than the maximum). correct the error and try again"*

**Convert the whole column data type to 202 adVarWChar:**
As the above code works for entries when they are formatted as text, we had an idea to see if we could pull the whole column of data in directly as text, we have experimented with Casting and Convert but cannot get it to work - I no longer have the sample code we were trying for that. I recall experimenting adding IMEX=1 to the connection string, but this didn't seem to make any difference.

**Apply a Find/Replace query on a whole column:**
Instead of retrieving the data and looping through it, we had an idea to apply a find and replace query directly on the column, similar to how we are able to trim a whole column. Again, we were unable to find any code/queries which worked.

**Create an empty record set and set the column type to String:**
We had an idea to create a blank/empty record set and manually set the date column to a string type, and then loop through the retrieved data and move them into the new record set. We didn't get very far with this as we weren't too sure how to create a blank RS, then we also thought, how would we write this data back to the worksheet - as I don't think you can write back to a closed workbook.

Here is the code I have at the moment:

```vb
Sub DataTesting()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

'set the workbook path of the file we want to read from
Dim workbookFileName As String
workbookFileName = "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\myWorkbook.xls"

'create a connection string
Dim connectionString As String
connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _
    & workbookFileName _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"";" 'IMEX=1"";"

'open the connection
Dim conn As ADODB.connection
Set conn = New ADODB.connection
conn.connectionString = connectionString
conn.Open

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

'Convert all data in the date column to a valid date (e.g. replace dates with decimals 1.1.21 to 01/01/2021)

'set query to select all data from the date column
Dim query As String
query = "SELECT * FROM [DATA SHEET$B2:B100]"  'col B is the Date column

With rs
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    '.Fields.Append "Date", adVarChar, 20, adFldMayBeNull   'NOT WORKING
    .CursorType = adOpenDynamic
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .Source = query
    .Open

    If Not .BOF And Not .EOF Then
        While (Not .EOF)
            If InStr(rs.Fields("Date").Value, ".") > 0 Then rs.Fields("Date").Value = Replace(rs.Fields("Date").Value, ".", "/")
            .MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
    .Close
End With

conn.Close

GoTo CleanUp

ErrorHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description 'THIS WILL BE WRITTEN TO TXT FILE

CleanUp:
'ensure the record set is equal to nothing and closed
If Not (rs Is Nothing) Then
    If (rs.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If

'ensure the connection is equal to nothing and closed
If Not (conn Is Nothing) Then
    If (conn.State And adStateOpen) = adStateOpen Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
End If

End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**
I am now able to read the data using the following query:

```
"SELECT IIF([Date] IS NULL, NULL, CSTR([Date])) AS [Date] FROM [DATA SHEET$B2:B10]"
```

This will only work if I set IMEX=1, which is only read-only. I am able to loop through each item and print out the value / detect where the dots are, but I cannot then amend them!

As mentioned by @Doug Coats I can move the data into an array, perform the manipulation on the array. But how exactly do I then put that array back into the recordset?

I guess I would need to close the first 'read only' connection, and re-open it as a 'write' connection. Then somehow run an update query - but how do I replace the existing record set values with the values from the array?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of looping through an ADO recordset, you should dump the set into an array and process there. It is faster, you wont run into errors and you can build the appropriate updates (or whatever else) on the fly. Honestly, when working with recordsets in VBA, my default behavior is to move into an array immediately, even though I will admit that might not be necessary 100% of the time. My experience of working with access has taught me many things and one of them being that I hate recordsets lol

Comment: Thanks for the advice, if I dump the data into an array, how do I write it back to the workbook without opening it? Cheers

Comment: you can send an ADO update statement, like in the answers suggestion.

Comment: you can also for go the SQL approach and just set the worksheet ot the array contents

Comment: Ok, so the conversion to array / update statement sounds good. I've managed to convert the RS to an Array, once I do the manipulation, how would I use the update statement to replace the original RS values to the array values? I think I might have to use 2 connections, one with IMEX=1 to let me read the values to put them into the array. And then a 2nd one with IMEX=0 to actually change the values in the recordset. As IMEX=1 will not let me amend the data - it says the db is read only,

Comment: can you just set the worksheet values?

Comment: Can you give me an example? I don't know how to do this?

Comment: Have you considered using the array approach without ADO? i.e. open the workbook, read the data into an array, process it, write it back to the workbook, close workbook. P.S How are you converting the recordset to an array? Are you using GetRows?

Comment: @norie - we originally started off the project by opening the workbook, manipulating and saving/closing, however, we have to perform this on multiple workbooks and the timeframe we have to do it in means its not fast enough. Yes, I am using GetRows to convert from RS to Array.

Comment: Were you originally using the array approach?

Comment: @norie yes, it worked well, but was taking quite a while,,, update, we have decided to revert back to the array approach, we have modified a few bits and managed to speed it up a little, We have also been told we can start the process running earlier that originally thought, so it doesn't matter that it may take a little longer than ADO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try an update query

```vb
    Const SQL = " UPDATE [DATA SHEET$] " & _
                " SET [Date] = REPLACE([Date],""."",""/"")" & _
                " WHERE INSTR([Date],""."") > 0 "

    Dim n
    conn.Execute SQL, n
    MsgBox n & " records updated"

Sub testdata()
   Dim wb, ws, i
   Set wb = Workbooks.Add
   Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
   ws.Name = "DATA SHEET"
   ws.Cells(1, 2) = "Date"
   For i = 2 To 10
      If Rnd() > 0.5 Then
         ws.Cells(i, 2) = "27.07.21"
      Else
         ws.Cells(i, 2) = "27/07/21"
      End If
   Next
   wb.SaveAs "c:\temp\so\dates.xls"
   wb.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: This partially works, similar to the issue I had when the majority of the inputs are correctly formatted. If I remove all of the dd/mm/yy dates, then it works perfect, if I leave them in, and have 1 dd.mm.yy dates, then it just misses it and n = 0.

Comment: Also, if I re-add in IMEX=1 in the connection string, I get the error "Operation must use an updateable query"

Comment: @pezz I have added code to create a test file, try that.

Comment: thanks, I can see you are creating a workbook with a list of dates, but it won't save, although I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @pezz Change the path to your test file `C:\Users\xxx\xxx\myWorkbook.xls`. This test file works with my code so as a first step I want to establish if it also works for you.

Comment: Ok, I am with you,,, I have saved off myWorkbook.xls and set my connection string to it. I can see you have entered 9 dates: 6 with the dot, 3 with a slash. - your code runs perfect, I changed the entries so that there were more slash's than dot's - again your code works. Finally, I noticed my 'live' workbook has the column formatted as ShortDate and myWorkbook is formatted as General, so I changed the column to ShortDate to match, and again, your code still works!  I linked my connection string to another 'live' workbook - as I have plenty to test with, and unfortunately, it doesn't work!

Comment: Thanks for your help @CDP1802 I have no idea why your suggested code doesn't work on our live workbooks - do you think the file format could be the reason, I looked in the properties, the ss was made in 2005! So no idea what version of Excel it was made. It's a poorly designed SS, white space in the headings, no alt + enter for new lines, pre-fixed column values with whitespace at the end! Like I said, we are unable to create a new template, so bit of a frustrating project this! - as mentioned in other comments, we have been given an extended time window, so we can revert to the array approach

Comment: @pezz When you said "the template was created years ago" I though the problem might age related. I tried creating a versions Excel 97-2003 Workbook with `FileFormat := xlExcel8` but it still worked so I suspect it may be compatible but not identical to your template.